# Access denied with root user s3, with Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I tried using the root access and secret key, got an access denied error.  I tried regenerating the keys, and used the new keys and was still denied access.  I've also tried creating an IAM user, granting it full s3access, along with creating a bucket policy as follows below and still got an access denied error.  Any help would be appreciated!  I know I can solve this problem by making the bucket public, and it's for my own portfolio website and I'm the only person who would ever be uploading photos to this site, however, I know this isn't good practice and would like to figure out why I am getting this error.

```
{
"Id": "Policy***********",
"Version": "2012-10-17",
"Statement": [
    {
        "Sid": "Stmt1545097638***",
        "Action": "s3:*",
        "Effect": "Allow",
        "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::my-bucket-name",
        "Principal": {
            "AWS": [
                "arn:aws:iam::iamidhere:user/useridhere"
            ]
        }
    }
  ]
}
```

I also updated the above bucket policy to include the root credentials for the user id and user name, still with access denied.  I restarted the rails server, closed out of the localhost I'm testing this on and restarted the entire process but to no luck.  Yes I've switched the access keys and made sure I'm using the right ones depending on if it was for the root user or the IAM user I created.

My local .env file

```
S3_BUCKET_NAME=bucket-name
AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID=*************
AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY=************
AWS_REGION=us-east-1
```

I'm using the carrierwave-aws gem, my carrierwave.rb file:

```
 CarrierWave.configure do |config|
  config.storage    = :aws
  config.aws_bucket = ENV.fetch('S3_BUCKET_NAME') 
  config.aws_acl    = 'public-read'

  config.aws_authenticated_url_expiration = 60 * 60 * 24 * 7

  config.aws_attributes = {
    expires: 1.week.from_now.httpdate,
    cache_control: 'max-age=604800'
  }

  config.aws_credentials = {
    access_key_id:     ENV.fetch('AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID'),
    secret_access_key: ENV.fetch('AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY'),
    region:            ENV.fetch('AWS_REGION'), 
    stub_responses:    Rails.env.test? 
  }
end
```

I've attempted both answers below with no success!

Comment: I should add I get an Aws::S3::Errors::AccessDenied when attempting to upload an image on my localhost.  The photos are not uploading at all as there are no objects in my bucket.

Answer (score 1):

Create a new IAM User and attach below policy to that user and try it, it's working on my server.

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                        "s3:GetBucketLocation",
                        "s3:ListAllMyBuckets"
                      ],
            "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::*"
        },
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": "s3:*",
            "Resource": [
                "arn:aws:s3:::YOUR-BUCKET",
                "arn:aws:s3:::YOUR-BUCKET/*"
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: This did not seem to work for me, still getting access denied!

Answer (score 0):

Your bucket policy isn't allowing access to the resources inside the bucket, just the bucket in general, you need to add a policy that allows something like the following:

```
{
    "Id": "Policy***********",
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "Stmt1545097638***",
            "Action": "s3:*",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Resource": [
                "arn:aws:s3:::bucketnamehere",
                "arn:aws:s3:::bucketnamehere/*"
            ],
            "Principal": {
                "AWS": [
                    "arn:aws:iam::ACCOUNTID:user/USERNAME"
                ]
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

Then give your user access to the objects with the following policy:

```
{
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": "s3:*",
            "Resource": [
                "arn:aws:s3:::BUCKETNAME",
                "arn:aws:s3:::BUCKETNAME/*"
            ]
        }
```

Comment: Any reason I would be denied access to upload to the bucket with root user credentials?

Comment: Is the second policy an IAM user policy, or an additional add on to the bucket policy?

Comment: I added first policy to my bucket, and second to my IAM group that the user is part of, still received access denied!

Comment: Can you try the above without setting an ACL on the bucket? So just create a bucket with no specific ACL and try to upload something etc.